# How to resolve the CSS warning in Firefox 71 version

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, css-selectors

I got the CSS warning in console window when load the my page in Firefox's latest version (71.0). Please find the list of warning on below.

```
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped. material.css:3943:11
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-clear’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. material.css:3958:15
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. material.css:3988:15
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.

Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-autofill’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. material.css:5611:40
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-textarea-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.

Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector. material.css:540:13
Error in parsing value for ‘margin-right’.  Declaration dropped.
```

[image]

Can you please provide a solution to resolve the warning from the Firefox browser.

Thanks 
Gobala

Comment: Remove or fix the erranous rules. Or just turn off the CSS warnings.

Comment: Ignore the warnings, the ignored CSS is for compatibility with other browsers.

Comment: is there any solution in CSS level without removing browser compatibility & off the warning in Firefox ?

Answer (score 2):

The warning is just that - a warning, not an error.

In effect, it is saying

"I don't know what this `-ms-input-placeholder` is, so I'm going to ignore it."

That's *exactly* what you want to happen, you want this specific browser to ignore any styling that is defined for a specific other browser.